# Finding the distance between row vector and column vector?

Tags: vectors

> Find the distance and angle between $2\underline{V_1}$ and $-\underline{V_2}$ where

> $\underline{V_1}$=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & -2 & 3  \end{pmatrix}

> and

> $\underline{V_2}^t$=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}

**My attempt**

When I derive $\underline{V_2}$ from the given data, I'm getting a column vector:

$\underline{V_2}$=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}

So is it possible to find distance between a row vector and a column vector? Please explain. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably, this is a typo.

Comment: This was my guess too. We can't preform subtraction on a row and column vector right? because vectors are not compatible. Shall I delete this question as it might cause confusion to other readers?